# Counting balances in fintech project

Tags: banking

We count balance by summarizing orders and this approach is too slow. However we have some ideas.

1. First idea is to cache balances and turnovers (it's already done but seems not enough)
2. Second is using a log table and update it after each transaction

What are the best practices counting balances in fintech project? Please suggest some solutions of our problem

Comment: I don't think this is answerable at this level of detail. Take one operation / batch that takes longer than you'd like and measure where the time is going. Nobody likes losing money to software bugs, so the prevalent best practice would be to prefer correctness over performance, then throw expensive hardware at it until it's fast enough...

Comment: "by summarizing orders" where are the orders? If they are in a database, it might be possible to get the sum via a database query and have it cached.

Comment: orders are stored in SQL DB and of course you can cache it but there are orders where status is pending and they can be pending for a long time